# Find harmonic of order $3$ for $2\pi$ periodic funciton $f(x) = \pi -|x|$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $f$ be a $2\pi$ periodic function such that $f(x) = \pi -|x|$ in
>   $[-\pi,\pi]$. Find its harmonic of order $3$

I'm learning about orthogonal families of polynmials and discrete polynomial approximations by fourier functions. I've came upon this exercise, but I don't know what an harmonic of order $3$ means.

Comment: So you have heard of Fourier series. Find the Fourier series of $f$ with $n=3$.

Comment: You know that $f(x) = \frac {a_0} 2 + \sum _{n \ge 1} (a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx)$. You are required to find $a_3$ and $b_3$. For this, use the formulae in your lecture notes.

Comment: @AlexM. could you point me to a material? I don't have lectur enotes about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to find the harmonic of order $3$ of that function. They are talking about Fourier series. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) to know more. We know $f$ is periodic, with period $T=2\pi$, so $f$ can be written as an infinite sum:

$$f(t) = \dfrac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\cos\left(\dfrac{2n\pi}{T} \,t \right) + \sin\left(\dfrac{2n\pi}{T} \,t \right) \right],$$

with

$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= \dfrac{2}{T} \int\limits_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(t) \, dt, \\
a_n &= \dfrac{2}{T} \int\limits_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(t) \cos \left( \dfrac{2n\pi}{T}\,t \right)  dt, \\
b_n &= \dfrac{2}{T} \int\limits_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(t) \sin \left( \dfrac{2n\pi}{T}\,t \right)  dt.
\end{align}$$

From here you can find $a_0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$, you could do that or you could find $a_3$ and $b_3$ (which are the terms of the harmonic of order 3). For example, to find the harmonic of order 5:

$$ \begin{align}
a_5 &= \dfrac{2}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\pi - |t|) \cos \left( \dfrac{2\cdot5 \pi}{2\pi}\,t \right)  dt, \\
&=\dfrac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{0} (\pi + t) \cos \left(5t \right)\, dt + \dfrac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} (\pi - t) \cos \left(5t \right)\, dt,
\end{align}$$

and

$$ \begin{align}
b_5 &= \dfrac{2}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\pi - |t|) \sin \left( \dfrac{2\cdot5 \pi}{2\pi}\,t \right)  dt, \\
&=\dfrac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{0} (\pi + t) \sin \left(5t \right)\, dt + \dfrac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} (\pi - t) \sin \left(5t \right)\, dt,
\end{align}$$

which is

$$a_5 \cos(5t) + b_5 \sin(5t).$$

Again, it's your choice: $a_n$ and $b_n$ and then substitute $n=3$ or find $a_3$ and $b_3$.